# integration constant with curves

Tags: differential-geometry

Say I have some tangent curve parametrized by arclength, $\alpha'(s)=T(s)$, and I want to retrieve the original curve $\alpha(s)$.

Say I'm given $\alpha'(s)=T(s) = (s,e^s,e^s)$

Is $\alpha = \int T(s)ds=(\frac{s^2}{2} +c,e^s + c,e^s + c)$

or do we integrate from $[0,L]$ and remove the constant?
Also what if we have $T'(s)$?

Comment: First, different constants. Second, where did $e^2$ come from? Third, of course $T(s)$ will need to be a unit vector for every $s$.

Comment: Thats my mistake it should be $e^s$. $\alpha = \int T(s)ds=(\frac{s^2}{2} +c_1,e^s + c_2,e^s + c_3)$

Comment: Right. :) .....

Comment: Okay thank you.